# How to tell GDB to disassemble N instructions at given address, also showing the raw bytes?

Tags: gdb, disassembly

I know two modes of GDB disassembly:

1. First command be used to show instructions as well as raw byte, but it seems to not accept number of instructions to disassemble — only memory range:

   `disas/r $pc,+30`
2. Second command can disassemble exactly N instructions, like follows, but without raw bytes:

   `x/10i $pc`

I'd like to have a hybrid of these two modes: make the raw bytes visible as in `disas/r` and be able to specify exact number of instructions to disassemble as in `x/10i`. Can I do it with GDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this.  (As an aside, it seems to me that this is a bit of an oversight and perhaps a bug report requesting that `x/i` be able to show the bytes would be good.)]

If you really need this, there is a way to implement it yourself.  The basic idea is to write a new command in Python.  This command could wrap the `disassemble` command (using `gdb.execute` with the `to_string` parameter), and then limit its output to `N` instructions.